# My WP7 Game is either not reading or writing from a IsolatedFileStream correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-io, xna-4.0, isolatedstoragefile

I'm attempting to add a local high score system to my game and have run int a brick wall with the file reading and writing, according to programmers and lecturers I know in real life and a few tutorials on the internet my code should be working as I want it to, however whenever I start my game my high score isn't loaded, below is my functions for both reading and writing to the file, are there any silly mistakes I'm making?

```
public void ReadHighScore()
    {
        byte[] myByteArray = new byte[64]; // Creates a new local byte array with a length of 64
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) // Creates an IsolatedStorageFile within the User Storage
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("highscore.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, store)) // Creates a new filestream attatched to the storage file
        {
            if (stream != null) // Checks to see if the filestream sucessfully read the file
            {
                int streamLength = (int)stream.Length; // Gets the length of the filestream
                stream.Read(myByteArray, 0, streamLength); // Parses the filestream to the byte array
            }
            else
                myState = (int)game_state.Terminate; // Temporary Error checking, the function gets though this without triggering the 'terminate' gamestate
        }

        string ScoreString = myByteArray.ToString(); // Parses the byte array to a string
        Int32.TryParse(ScoreString, out highScore.score); // Parses the string to an integer
    }

    public void SaveHighScore()
    {
        byte[] myByteArray = new byte[64]; // Creates a new local byte array with a length of 64
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) // Creates an IsolatedStorageFile within the User Storage
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("highscore.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, store)) // Creates a new filestream attatched to the storage file
        {
            if (stream != null) // Checks to see if the filestream sucessfully read the file
            {
                int streamLength = (int)stream.Length; // Gets the length of the filestream
                stream.Write(myByteArray, 0, streamLength); // Parses the byte array to the filestream
            }
            else
                myState = (int)game_state.Terminate; // Temporary Error checking, the function gets though this without triggering the 'terminate' gamestate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's a mistake in the reading part: you're opening the file with `FileMode.Create`.

And according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

So basically, your `ReadHighScore` is deleting the old file and creating a new one. Which is, I believe, not what you wanted to do. Replace `FileMode.Create` by `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` (only in the `ReadHighScore` method) and you should have a better result.

---

Also, there's an error in the `SaveHighScore`, on this line:

```
stream.Write(myByteArray, 0, streamLength);
```

Since you're creating the file, `streamLength` is supposed to be equal to 0. Therefore, you aren't writing anything. What you really want to do is:

```
stream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
```

You should consider using `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, `BinaryReader`, and `BinaryWriter` to read/write into streams, as they are far easier to use.

---

Last but not least, the data you're reading and writing is wrong. In the `SaveHighScore` method, you're trying to save an empty array, the actual high score is nowhere to be found. In the `ReadHighScore` method, it's even worse: you're reading `myByteArray.ToString()`, which will always be equal to `System.Byte[]`.

---

In the end, your code should be something like: (given that `highScore.score` is declared as `int`)

```
public void ReadHighScore()
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("highscore.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, store))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                highScore.score = reader.ReadInt32();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void SaveHighScore()
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("highscore.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, store))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(highScore.score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! And you've kinda shown me that even the stuff I can do can always be done cleaner, I've still got a lot to learn :)

Comment: The code still needs a little work, missed out an EndOfStreamException, so I guess I'll have to learn how to do those now :P thanks for the help!

Comment: @TotalJargon Indeed I missed that one. The first time you call `ReadHighScore`, the file will be empty to the `BinaryReader` will throw an exception. You have either to check the stream length beforehand, or check if the file exists before opening it (and exit the function if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Got it sort of working now although it's not working quite as I expected, the first time I ran the game the high score saving worked fine, however after running the game a second time the high score didn't update, is there anything I can do to make it overwrite the file instead of append to it (Which I'm guessing is what it's doing)? Thanks!

Comment: @TotalJargon That's what `FileMode.Create` is supposed to do I believe. In the worst case, just delete the file and create a new one.

Comment: changed it to FileMode.OpenOrCreate and messed about with the position of the function in the program, seems to work great now :P thanks for the help ^^

Comment: @TotalJargon It is customary to accept the answer if it solved your problem.